# Client likes to fiddle with my designs

Tags: logo, client-relations

I am designing a logo for a client. I've given her a few ideas and she wants to take 3 of them and work on them herself with her sister. We have a contract and she'll pay me so that's not the issue. I don't want her compromising my design! How do I share my feelings without being condescending? Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* is she asking for? [Native files?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/how-do-you-explain-the-value-of-native-files-to-an-uneducated-client)

Comment: @Scott Yes. She wants the native files.

Comment: Wait and see what she comes up with and then discuss the merits (or lack thereof) of what you see on a purely objective manner. At the end of the day, though, some client are like this. Might be best to smile, take the check, and then slink away.

Comment: Native files should be sold at high price and not be included with your final files. Native files are like a "recipe" of your work, you don't provide this for free or as part of the logo final files. Final files can be vectors but should not include the fonts or editable text. Plus, some people confuse these files and send them to printers or other designers... without the fonts vectorized... arghh.

Answer (score 2):

While I think this is a [duplicate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/how-do-you-explain-the-value-of-native-files-to-an-uneducated-client) in general, I'd like to add some info based on context of the question.

This is a **logo**. When I deliver final logo files, included are fully working vector files. There's no point in maintaing or restricting delivery of native files for *logos*. The client actually *needs* native files for their logo.

So, to this end, I'd probably provide some basic native files and let the client play with them. I'd strip out any custom patterns, brushes, etc. and simply provide basic flat files. I'd essentially "dumb down" the files to only the necessary elements and send those. Certainly no harm would come of this due to the nature of the project.

Now, if things start devolving into *"I can't edit this, can you send it to me in Word?"* Or some such nonsense, then you'll need to explain that you have specific tools you use and altering the working files to allow her to make adjustments was not what was agreed upon.

I state this because it is a **logo** project. My attitude towards providing native files is ***[markedly different](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8484/3270)*** for non-logo projects.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you shouldn't give her the files, since that's why she hired you. I think it's kind of a slap on my face if it's done to me even though the client will pay me for it.

I think you should just tell her that as a designer, it is with regret that you have to keep the designs and she would just have to tell you what she wants within the contract rules.

If you want to appear technical, tell her that you can give her the files, but it will require selling her the copyrights, which in turn will require them to pay a huge amount for each design, but this will remove *your* rights over the designs. Tell her that because you will no longer be able to place these in your portfolio or reuse the elements in the design, you will have to charge her more for it, although I think this option seems rather intimidating and passive aggressive.

If she insists, then I suggest giving her the files in minimal detail (maybe in one entire layer or in five layers and then in low resolution, or with a watermark, or something. If she complains, give her the first reason I stated, or make something up :)

I hope she doesn't insist, and I hope she just lets you design them within the contract rules!

All my hopes.