# When Clients ask for all of the fonts you use in their branding materials

Tags: fonts, business, client-relations

What is the correct way to handle a client if they ask you for all of your native design files and specifically the FONTS.

Do you charge them for the native files if they have already paid for the initial design of a flyer, brochure etc. Do you release copies of the fonts used in the design to them or charge them a fee for both native files and fonts or send them link to purchase their own fonts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you explain the value of native files to an uneducated client?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/how-do-you-explain-the-value-of-native-files-to-an-uneducated-client)

Comment: In legal terms, the client must *purchase* fonts. Whether you do that on their behalf or they do it, it needs to be done. You generally can't legally give away fonts any more than you could give away Illustrator. Fonts are software.

Comment: Embed font to final work and charge additional for fonts.

Comment: @SaturnsEye ... (Not a lawyer) - I could be wrong but I don't believe that's legal. You purchasing a font doesn't give you any rights to resell it to a 3rd party.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How do you charge for the native files if they ask for the native files?

Comment: Payton, we have A LOT on the topic: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=native+files

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I thought they was on about their own font as they said "your font".

Comment: @SaturnsEye oh good point. You could be right. Probably unlikely that they designed their own font, but you make a valid point that it isn't clear.

Comment: @Ryan probably unlikely yes, but it's what I would do if it was my own font :)

Comment: Payton, this will most directly answer your question about pricing (at least from my perspective): http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/charging-an-intellectual-property-transfer-fee-for-design-work/8484#8484

Comment: @Scott Your first comment is the correct response; you should make it an answer.

Comment: If you say so @LaurenIpsum :) I think the duplicate vote covers it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In legal terms, the client must purchase fonts. Whether you do that on their behalf or they do it, it needs to be done. You generally can't legally give away fonts any more than you could give away Illustrator. Fonts are software.