# Usage costs for logo animation intro / outro template

Tags: animation, licensing, freelance, fees

As a freelancer I recently produced three web animations for a client.

The company has just rebranded and I've been asked to create an animated logo intro / outro template (that's 2 x concepts, animation and sound design) for use on:

- The three existing videos
- 100 previously made videos (not made by me)
- All future web videos

The cost for the concepts, animation, sound design and adding the intro / outro to the existing three videos I can calculate easily enough but should I be charging extra for the additional usage and the fact this is a template that will likely be sent to other people to be added to any videos they are making for the same client?

If so, can anybody please advise on the best way to price that usage?

With voiceover fees I'm used to paying for usage or buyout.. same with music licensing but I've never had to consider the same with my own work.

I found this thread - [Charging an Intellectual Property transfer fee for design work](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/charging-an-intellectual-property-transfer-fee-for-design-work) - that suggests the following formula for design work:

"Final formula:
Design fee + (design fee x 3) + (third party licenses) = Fee for native files"

But I am totally unsure if that is appropriate in this case.

Any advice greatly appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the usage calcs done by professional photographers helped me a lot in the past - here's a link to a resource I've used before:

[AOP usage fee calculator](https://www.the-aop.org/information/usage-calculator)

A typical dayrate for a decent professional photographer in the US right now (where I am at the moment) is ~ $1000, so I start with that, and you should set based on the most common locally-applicable professional photographer's dayrate if your work is of high professional calibre.

Hope this helps mate.

Comment: Thank you - that's really helpful as a way to see approximate costs and how they are calculated. The info on the 'Explanation of BUR' page, alone, has opened my eyes - https://www.the-aop.org/information/usage-calculator/explanation-of-b-u-r. Interestingly, the usage I inputted is not too far off the formula from the previous post that I posted above. The only 'missing' piece for me is that I expect the usage to be in perpetuity and the max in the calculator is '10 Years' which ramps up the cost massively. Still, I have a ballpark figure with rationale which is great. Cheers.

Comment: For info, I used the calculator @GerardFalla posted as a starting point and sent costs to my client. He was totally surprised - it's an agency and the end client is a big brand if not a household name because it's a dullish product.. usage is Europe and US. Stuck to my guns with the concept of charging extra for usage but said I'd be prepared to lower the usage costs. I'll update with a decision when it comes.

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmcake -- good luck!

Comment: Well it didn't work out but thanks for the advice anyway.. I still think it was the right approach.

Comment: Sorry to hear that: better luck next time!